# Takes too much time to extract manifest of large file

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have a Revit file around 200MB. I am using forge SDK and below endpoint to extract manifest.
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/

However, process of extracting manifest is taking a HUGE amount of time, which is longer than 30 minutes. How can I shorten this period and prevent timeout issues? Is there any configuration to extract manifest of large files?

SDK version: Assembly Autodesk.Forge, Version=1.9.0.0

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it can happen that you submit a conversion job at a moment when there are many other jobs queued, and the system hasn't auto-scaled up to the increased load yet. It could also be an issue with pathological designs which might be causing the extraction to take an unusual long time to process.

If the issue persists, please consider sharing one of your designs (confidentially - we would not share it with anyone outside of Autodesk) via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com` so that we could debug the translation on our end.